# What is $ \sin(x)+\sin(x−π)+\sin(x+π) $?

Tags: trigonometry

So I have this trig question:

> $ \sin(x)+\sin(x−π)+\sin(x+π) = $ _____

The answer is $- \sin(x)$

I can't figure out how to solve it.

Any help?

Comment: Do you know the formula of sine of a sum?

Comment: Yep I do.......

Comment: @Afzal Then what does that formula tell you about $\sin(x-\pi)$? What about $\sin(x + \pi)$?

Comment: sin(x) cos (π) - sin (π) cos(x) + sin (x) cos(π) + sin(π)cos(x) , 2nd and fourth one cancels out and then you have sin(x) cos (π) +  sin (x) cos(π), if I add em then I just get 2 sin(x) 2cos(π). How do I reduce it down from this point

Comment: Do you know $\sin(\pi)$ and $\cos(\pi)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin(x)+\color{green}{\sin(x-\pi)}+\color{red}{\sin(x+\pi)}$$ $$=\sin(x)+\color{green}{\sin(x)\cos(-\pi)+\cos(x)\sin(-\pi)}+\color{red}{\sin(x)\cos(\pi)+\cos(x)\sin(\pi)}$$
$$=\sin(x)\color{green}{-\sin(x)}\color{red}{-\sin(x)}=-\sin(x)$$

using the formula for $\sin(x+\theta)$ and the facts that $\cos(\pm\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(\pm\pi)=0$

Comment: Aight this is v cool. You should have followed the signs of the general formula for expanding the second term tho, it makes it a little confusing to not do it.

Comment: You could say $\sin(x-\theta)=\sin(x)\cos(\theta)-\cos(x)\sin(\theta)$ or $\sin(x+(-\theta))=\sin(x)\cos(-\theta)+\cos(x)\sin(-\theta);$  they're the same because $\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$ and $-\sin(\theta)=\sin(-\theta)$

Comment: This is great, thanks man.

Answer (score 4):

As shown in some other answers, this is very simple *if you know that*:
$$\sin(x-\pi)=-\sin x \quad\mbox{and}\quad \sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$$
If you don't know these formulas or you have a hard time understanding why they are true, you should spend some time to carefully study the unit circle and how symmetry there leads to these simple relations.

The image below should help you understand why $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$.

[image]

Then note that by "adding a full cirle", the same holds for the angle $x-\pi$:
$$\sin(x-\pi)=\sin(x-\pi\color{blue}{+2\pi})=\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$$

Comment: Wow man, this was very neat

Comment: You're welcome; it's worth being able to work and reason with the unit circle when it comes to these basic properties of the trig. functions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably know, that $$ \sin(x−\pi) = -\sin(x).$$

Also $$\sin(x+\pi) = \sin(x-\pi + 2\pi) = \sin(x-\pi)$$ so your given expression reduces to $$\sin x - \sin x - \sin x$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin(\pi -x)=\sin x$ and $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin x$, using which we get:

$$\begin{aligned}\lambda&=\sin x+\sin(x-\pi)+\sin(x+\pi)\\&= \sin x-\sin(\pi -x)+\sin(\pi+x)\\&=\sin x-\sin x-\sin x=-\sin x\end{aligned}$$

$$\sin(\pi -x)=\sin \pi \cos x-\sin x\cos\pi=+\sin x \\ \sin(\pi+x)=\sin\pi\cos x+\sin x\cos \pi =-\sin x$$

Comment: Wait where did you get sin(π−x)=sinx and sin(π+x)=−sinx from? Aren't you supposed to apply the sin(alpha+beta) = sin(alpha)cos(beta) + cos(alpha)sin(beta) to it?

Comment: @Afzal: Did you try to apply $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ formula? Try and see that $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin x$

Comment: Yea I wasn't evaluating the value of π in sine so that was messing it all up.

Comment: @Afzal: Good, now you may try to obtain other useful formulas for $\sin(\pi/2-x)$, $\sin(\pi/2+x)$

Comment: sin(π/2−x) = cos (-x) and  sin(π/2+x)  = cos (x)?

Comment: Yes that is true @Arkilo Notice that $\cos x$ is an even function i.e. $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: @ParasKhosla Holy sheet man, I came here a little frustrated from hw, and now I have a math b*ner